# Javascript button toggle not working on first click, only second click or more

Tags: javascript, button, toggle

I'm not sure what's going on here, but I have this javascript toggle button on the top left of my video that I'm using to swap the video embed source and to change the closed captioning text of the toggle from "cc on" to "cc off" and back... but it only works after an initial click. What am I missing here?

Console shows a "Button not defined" on page load, but I'm not sure what isn't right.

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <button id="togglecc" value="OFF" onclick="toggle(this);">cc on</button>
</div>
<div id="player">
  <div id="la1-video-player" data-embed-id="87e859b2-5db8-4ad8-bac7-575c22288930"></div>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://control.livingasone.com/webplayer/loader.min.js"></script>
</div>
```

Script:

```
function toggle(button) {
  v = document.getElementById("togglecc");
  vp = document.getElementById("player");
  if (v.value == "ON") {
    v.value = "OFF";
    v.innerHTML = 'cc off';
    vp.innerHTML = '<div id="la1-video-player" data-embed-id="9257a531-25ce-48bd-821b-9335681c45d8"></'+'div>';var a=document.createElement("script");a.setAttribute("src","//control.livingasone.com/webplayer/loader.min.js");document.getElementById('player').appendChild(a);
  } else {
    v.value = "ON";
    v.innerHTML = 'cc on';
    vp.innerHTML = '<div id="la1-video-player" data-embed-id="87e859b2-5db8-4ad8-bac7-575c22288930"></'+'div>';var a=document.createElement("script");a.setAttribute("src","//control.livingasone.com/webplayer/loader.min.js");document.getElementById('player').appendChild(a);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/milkboy31/tg02Lv4c/

Comment: Your button starts with `value="OFF"` and label "cc on", surely that's not right?

Comment: as @GuyIncognito pointed out, matching the value with the text solves the problem

Comment: Likely I was confused on having the captions "off" by default and the button reading "on" to turn them on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your updated fiddle

[toggle button](https://jsfiddle.net/169c4fpw/12/)

Also you should avoid calling function on button element like this

```
onclick="toggle(this);"
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the changes! It works great. Follow up would be, what would I need to do to hide that class "navbar" div unless the "player" div is moused over?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/milkboy31/tg02Lv4c/21/ is the newest and I have the mouseover working. Thanks.